# Get item name in drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am working on an angular app. I am using drag and drop in my application for reordering list. Code is as follows:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-sortable?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {
  movies = [
    'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
    'Episode II - Attack of the Clones',
    'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith',
    'Episode IV - A New Hope',
    'Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
    'Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
    'Episode VII - The Force Awakens',
    'Episode VIII - The Last Jedi'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example-list {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example-box {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-box:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

I want that whenever I drag and drop a item, I want to have it's name in a variable. Like if I drag and drop 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace' then I want to store 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace' in a variable. I have currentIndex in event.currentIndex but how can I get the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name with the help of currentIndex. You have currentIndex just pass the current index in your movies array.

`this.movies[event.currentIndex]`

1. First create a variable

   - `name: string = "";`
2. In your **drop** function add the following line

   - `this.name = this.movies[event.currentIndex]`

Now the name will be stored in **name** variable. Like if you drag and drop 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace' then 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace' will store in a **name** variable.

[StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-sortable-d8xeo8?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Look through the `drop` event, everything is there.

HTML view

```
<div (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
```

Controller

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<tasks[]>) {
    console.log(event.item.data); // your dropped item
  }
```